# I'm trying to implement the Lapis JSF Exporter use PrimeFaces 5.3

Tags: jsf, primefaces, exporter

In 2.1.20 version jsf error occurs and the Project NOT rises

> Abr 26, 2016 5:29:21 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks GRAVE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [javax.faces.context.FacesContext$1] (value [javax.faces.context.FacesContext$1@1e0429c3]) and a value of type [org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.StartupFacesContextImpl] (value [org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.StartupFacesContextImpl@2351d09a]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak

In the 2.1.28 version jsf the project up and Using the JSF Lapis Exporter occurs Error:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Fonte: https://github.com/rdicroce/jsfexporter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After verification , I identified that in my pom.xml file was using the premises " api and impl " MyFaces with the " api and impl " JSF is conflict , after removing the jsf dependencies work.

MY pom.xml...

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
        <version>${myfaces.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
    <version>${myfaces.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

comment or remove...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.28</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.28</version>
</dependency>
```